# PDF generation using HTML Doc Software in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webserver, exe, html2pdf

I am converting a website from 1.1 framework to 4.0. The website has functionality to Generate Pdf of the content entered in TextEditor. this website has used "**HTMLDoc Software**" to convert content to pdf using the below code:

```
string url, pdfFile, exeFile;
        string response = "";
 url = GetWebUrl() + "/PDFSpeechDetails.aspx?ArticleId=" + ValueOfQueryString;
                pdfFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "pdfs\\articles\\" + ValueOfQueryString + ".pdf";
                exeFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "html2pdf\\htmldoc.exe";
                response = gPDF.ShowPDF(url, pdfFile, exeFile);
```

and **ShowPDF** Method is:

```
 public string ShowPDF(string url, string pdfFile, string exeFile)
    {
        try
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = exeFile;
            pdfFile = "\"" + pdfFile + "\"";
            string args = " --webpage -f " + pdfFile + " " + url;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;

            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            return "1";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

What the above code is doing:(as the previous developer used)
I have placed a folder named **HTML2PDf** has an exe file. i am just passing it to argument and running this exe file.

This code is working fine on my local machine as well as on server(I took remote of the server and checked there.), but when i tried to generate the PDF from Outer world means using website's domain name, it does not work. I am not getting any clue why it is not working.
please help me how can i make it working on website.

Comment: Did you turn on Developer Tools (usually F12 key on Chrome or later versions of IE) or use TCP Trace or Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) and look at the network reponse and try and see what is actually happening when you press the Generate PDF Button

Comment: can you share error or share the live url(website's domain link) for the same?